# Analytics api returning unauthorised

Tags: rest-api, httprequest, analytics, analytics-api

I am using following Endpoint url

```
/services/data/v37.0/analytics/reports/00O280000037Ls3?includeDetails=true
```

It is working perfect in Workbench.
I can see the Raw response.
But when I put it in the Apex set Endpoint it returns error

> [{"message":"The request body is either invalid or incomplete.","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]

Code is here

```
      String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;
      Http h = new Http();
      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
      req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_Token);
      req.setBody(reqbody);
      req.setMethod('GET');
      req.setEndpoint('https://teeofftech-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/analytics/reports/00O280000037Ls3?includeDetails=true');
      HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 

      return string.valueOf(res.getbody());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running this from within salesforce and have already logged in, the most convenient way to make this call would be to get the session id from UserInfo:

```
Http h = new Http(); 
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint('https://teeofftech-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/analytics/reports/00O280000037Ls3?includeDetails=true');
HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 

return string.valueOf(res.getbody());
```

Comment: Thanks Martin It works. Can you pl tell me is there any way to convert this JSON to csv format?

Comment: There isn't a way of doing it directly as far as I know. Typically the data structures that you get back from the analytics api are too complex for a csv anyways.

Comment: what do you think which is better way to get these reports in csv formats?

Comment: If you are just pulling out raw data, a bulk api query works well.

Comment: If the raw JSON can be handed over to Javascript. We can get a CSV download.

Comment: But Sangram I have to schedule this class so there will be no any role of javascript.